# Why does IE break my page?

Tags: html

I've got a simple page built with for our city's website. Firefox and chrome like it fine... IE breaks it to pieces.
I've tried my code in the W3School tryit editor and it comes out fine there.
The page address is:
http://www.ci.douglasville.ga.us/index.aspx?NID=509

And here's the offending code:

```
<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" style="text-align: justify; width: 100%; " align="left">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 350px; ">
        <div style="text-align: center;"><span style="line-height: 17px; text-align: -webkit-auto; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); "></span></div>
        <span style="line-height: 17px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); "><b style="LINE-HEIGHT: 17px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(255,255,255)">ADULT KARATE
        FOR ALL AGES &amp; SIZES!</b><br style="LINE-HEIGHT: 17px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(255,255,255)">
        <br>
        This is the
        chance you&rsquo;ve been waiting for to get healthy and more active!</span><br style="LINE-HEIGHT: 17px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(255,255,255)">
        <br style="LINE-HEIGHT: 17px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(255,255,255)">
        <span style="line-height: 17px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); ">The McClure Style
        of TaeKwonDo specializes in safe, affordable, quality training for all adults,
        regardless of age, experience, or fitness level. All are welcome!</span><br style="LINE-HEIGHT: 17px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(255,255,255)">
        <br style="LINE-HEIGHT: 17px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(255,255,255)">
        <span style="line-height: 17px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); ">Our Black-Belt
        Instructors tailor all classes to meet your specific needs and skill
        level:</span><span style="line-height: 17px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); "> </span><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: -webkit-auto; line-height: 17px; ">
        </span></td>
        <td style="border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: thin; border-top-color: rgb(44, 75, 129); border-right-style: solid; border-right-width: thin; border-right-color: rgb(44, 75, 129); border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: thin; border-bottom-color: rgb(44, 75, 129); border-left-style: solid; border-left-width: thin; border-left-color: rgb(44, 75, 129); background-color: rgb(229, 225, 226); width: 205px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; ">
        <div style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-weight: bold; line-height: 17px; color: rgb(128, 104, 39); ">Contact</span></div>
        <span style="line-height: 17px; background-color: rgb(229, 225, 226); ">
        <span style="line-height: 17px; background-color: rgb(229, 225, 226); ">Tommy Nicholson,
        Instructor<br>
        <div>Ph:
        770-942-0018<br>
        <br>
        Denver Thompson, Instructor<br>
        770-595-1245</div>
        </span>
        <div class=""><br>
        <b>Hunter Park Community Center</b></div>
        </span><span style="line-height: 17px; text-align: left; ">
        8830 Gurley Road<br>
        Douglasville, Ga 30134<br>
        To sign up call 770-920-3007<br>
        </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; " colspan="2">
        <ul>
            <li><span style="line-height: 17px; ">Self-Defense Training</span></li>
            <li><span style="line-height: 17px; ">Fitness, Flexibility, Coordination, &amp; Balance Training</span></li>
            <li><span style="line-height: 17px; ">Rank Advancements at Your Own Pace</span></li>
            <li><span style="line-height: 17px; ">Advanced Training in TaeKwonDo and Hapkido for Experienced Skill Levels</span></li>
        </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; " colspan="2">&nbsp;
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left;width: 280px; vertical-align: top; "><b>Adult Classes</b><br>
                    Registration: Every Tuesday (ongoing)<br>
                    <br>
                    Classes: Tuesdays, 7:30-8:30pm<br>
                    Cost: $50.00 per month<br>
                    <br>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 280px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; "><b style="text-align: left; "></b><b>Karate for Kids</b><br>
                    Registration: Winter Classes begin Tuesday, <span class="Apple-tab-span" style="white-space: pre; ">            </span>November 15, 2011<br>
                    Classes: Tuesdays, 6:30-7:30 pm<br>
                    Cost: $60.00 per month for 8 week course<span style="text-align: -webkit-auto; "></span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: What do you mean, break it? the menus in IE are jumping a bit lower than it should be?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to spot the problem with proper indentation.

Comment: because microsoft made it, bro

Comment: Not really related to your issue, but if you cleaned up your markup by removing in-line styles not only would it be easier to read but easier to maintain in the future. That's not even broaching the subject of using a table for your layout which can, among other things, make future upkeep a nightmare.

Comment: 9 is what i've got and shows wierd. https://picasaweb.google.com/115243096411991911722/Web?feat=directlink#5675689521666006274

Comment: Perhaps IE does not break your web page, but rather IE is broken and your web page is able to demonstrate it? Jus' sayin.

Comment: so trash tables.... whats my next choice/step css?

Comment: Break your page into sections and you can use Div's and css to keep the layout. You pretty much already have that with the elements that are wrapped in the table all you really need is some CSS to position things like the table does.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an IE7 doctype, thus your page is displaying with IE7's rendering engine.  Why not use an IE9 doctype, such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

**Edit:** Of course, you want it to display properly in IE7, so you'll still want to fix the issue.  In the "Karate for Kids" cell, you have a span with `white-space: pre;`.  This is causing your problem.  The easiest fix is to insert a `<br/>` just before it.

---

That being said, your page uses some layout techniques that are contrary to web design best practices.  You are using tables to control layout and presentation, which is frowned upon to say the least, but ironically, you are not using tables to display the tabular data on the page.  I'd also particularly discourage splitting the footer city logo image in half.

Comment: the bottom table is what IE jumbles

Comment: it's all being built in a proprietary back end editor from Civic Plus. I can do code or wysiwyg. i've made the table and then inserted a smaller 2 cell table in the last cell. chrome and firefox render it fine while IE kills it and then spreads everything else out

Comment: @NathanTodd - The easiest fix is to insert a `<br/>` before the span with `white-space: pre`.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://www.ci.douglasville.ga.us/index.aspx?NID=509) finds several problems, you should consider yourself lucky that only IE does not display the page properly. The validator also gives information on what you can do to fix the problems.